# why wont his imageview rotate?

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to rotate an image view at its center. When I click on the image, it wont rotate. Any reason why?

```
        refreshResults.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            //how to start it.
            refreshResults.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you should switch to new anim api's

Comment: which are what?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html like `refreshResults.animate().rotation(360).start();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this its working for me.

```
RotateAnimation myAnim = new RotateAnimation(0, 45, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

myAnim .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
myAnim .setDuration(500);
myAnim .setFillEnabled(true);
myAnim .setFillAfter(true);

image.startAnimation(myAnim )
```

Comment: spins VERY slowly.

Comment: myAnim .setDuration(100);
Its duration time in miliseconds you can set it according to your need.

Comment: thanks. please dont ask people to accept your answer though.

Comment: If it resolves your issue then its your responsibility to accept the answer Thanks.